# Trusting the new sysadmin

Tags: active-directory, permissions

(using a throwaway account for obvious reasons, should this not be the right place for this, please let me know)

Hello fellow Sysadmins,
I've been hired at a smallish company to be the sole sysadmin. The company currently works with an MSP to handle all of their IT and they wish to insource most of the work, which is why they hired me.

I'm supposed to take over, among other things, responsibility for Active Directory. I've had a look at the current setup, suggested a few improvements and said I'd need a dedicated administrative account within the Domain Admins group. I then proceed to explain why I'd need it, what it would be used for and how I'd like to implement auditing to keep management aware of what I'm doing. I also explained that auditing is not 100% foolproof, and since I'd be the one to set it up, I'd necessarily also have the necessary permissions to turn it off. I guess I was trying to make everybody aware that there are limitations and I am after all the admin...that's why I was hired.

Bossman gets visibly worried and asks if I'd also have access to a file share with some confidential stuff (payrolls, personnel files, whatever...). "Not explicitly, but being the administrator I could grant myself the necessary permissions", I explain. Apparently that was the *WRONG* thing to say. Bossman says I need to figure out some sort of process to make sure any administrative tasks get supervised by a manager.

I honestly find this approach quite offensive. I can understand I'm new and he doesn't know me, but he hired me to do precisely THIS job and I am after all an experienced system administrator with excellent references!

Now, getting to the point and putting my feelings aside, I've had a look at possible solutions to either audit my domain admin account and generally admin tasks or enable 2FA and I haven't been able to find a solution that's

1. cheap
2. I cannot disable with domain admin privileges and physical access to the server and
3. allows me to work in an emergency when none of the managers are around/available (they often travel abroad concurrently and are not available via phone/email).

So far I've had a look at Netwrix Auditor (https://www.netwrix.com/active_directory_auditing.html), AD Auditing, ESET Secure Authentication (https://www.eset.com/us/business/endpoint-security/two-factor-authentication) and smartcards for 2FA. None meets the above criteria.

Does anyone have any experience working in such an environment? Should I get worried about my future here?

Please note I don't work for a government/defense/security contractor, there's currently no legislation requiring me to be supervised and the company does not handle PII except for that of it's employees.

Any input is appreciated!

EDIT: as someone pointed out on workplace.stackexchange.com that cross-posting is discouraged, let me rephrase the above as a technical question: does anyone know of a product that fits the above criteria?

Comment: Question, is it even possible to find any solution that works with point 1 + 2? And regarding "your future" - well, yes. Your job may be good, but you will always have the feeling that they do not trust you.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://workplace.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks for the tip, xposted it there too.

Comment: @Orphans, honestly I doubt 2 is possible at all. Domain Admin privileges mean I have the right to do anything whatsoever, and without those privileges I cannot do my job (manage AD), that's why I'm discouraged (to put it mildly) by the boss's reaction.

Comment: This fits better on WP, it's crossposted and we don't domproduct recommendations.